# React Hook useEffect for fetching and posting to Backend (API)?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

That’s more a question to know more of how you guys commonly do it as a problem. I’m currently having no problem with the code, but I’m not pretty sure that’s the right way to do that.

In my code I have a fetch (with Axios) for the data in the Backend (a simple list with objects). And for that I’m using the new React hooks with useEffect, works like a charm:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/list")
      .then(result => {
        setExampleList(result.data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, [setExampleList]);
```

But I also have a screen where the process to add to that list in Backend comes. And for that I’m handling the form submit also with axios in Backend. And that’s the “problem”. It works and goes to Backend but my fetch was not updating, because it was not rerendered or something. Then I came up with the ideia to call the setData() where the fetching lives  inside the function for adding a new item (after posting it):

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let obj = {
      name: name,
      city: city
    };
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/api/add", obj)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        obj.id = response.data.inserted_id;
        setExampleList([...setExampleList, obj]);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    handleCloseModal();
  }
```

And that works, but as you can imagine, a little “fake” because the data is not really what in Backend is until I reload the page. So, have you guys done something in this way? What would be the best solution in that case?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Hello! Thanks for replying. I’m sorry to not post the code. Thought that could be a question without posting it. Giving thumbs down it’s not so cool. But ok. I edit the question with the code!

Comment: Edited the question with the code (Y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common practice to "fake" update a list even if you didn't have a refresh problem. This is because you want your app to seem fast to the user. If the backend request take 5 sec to complete and then updates the screen the user is going to think your app is broken.

In chat apps it is extremely common to show a message as sent before it actual gets sent. The same concept is used a lot for deleting items. The item gets removed from the screen immediately before the backend is updated and a refresh is not needed.

You may want to add an UI message that tells the user if the submit failed so they don't refresh the page and wonder why the list is missing new items.

So to answer your questions

> Have you guys done something in this way? Yep!
>
> What would be the best solution in that case? If the list is for a single user then your solution is great.

That being said if you are expecting multiple users to be updating the list at the same time then you are going to want to sync the list before a page refresh.

Comment: Wow. Cool explanation. Thanks! So, my app is going to have one list for each user. Which one (logged will have one of it, that said I think it’s ok). But I’m currently doing some work in the data that came from frontend in Backend and maybe need to reload it. Any idea how could it be done? Should I call the axios fetch for list again? I’ll edit the question with my code

Comment: I have it! Created a function to handle the fetch for listing and after handling the form I call this function :) btw thanks for your great explanation and I will accept it as the right solution, because was more focused on about the architecture as to solve the problem and you really helped a lot.